# Passing information between sub in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, call, vba

I am trying to take an array from one sub to another so that it can be used for calculations. After the calculations are done I need to send them back to the the first sub. Here is my code and when I run it absolutely nothing happens.

```
Public Sub SampleStats()
Option Explicit

Dim n As Integer        ' sample size
Dim x() As Double       ' array containing x values
Dim i As Integer        ' loop counter
Dim rang As Double

' variables to hold output from computation subroutines
Dim minVal As Double        ' minimim value
Dim maxVal As Double        ' maximum value
Dim mean As Double          ' mean value
Dim var As Double           ' variance
Dim stdDev As Double        ' standard deviation

' get sample size
Sheets("Q1_Stats").Select
Range("B8").Select
n = ActiveCell.Value

' create an array
ReDim x(n - 1)            ' redimension x now that we know how many values we have

' get x values
Range("B11").Select
For i = 0 To n - 1
    x(i) = ActiveCell.Offset(i)
Next i

' Call subroutine to compute statistics
 ' *** put your call statemenAst below (with arguments)
Call ComputeStatistics(x(), n)

 ' Call ComputeStatistics(ByVal ..., ByRef ..., ... )

' now output results
Range("F9").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0).Value = minVal

Range("F10").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0).Value = maxVal

Range("F11").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0).Value = rang

Range("F12").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0).Value = mean

Range("F13").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0).Value = var

Range("F14").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0).Value = stdDev

End Sub

Sub ComputeStatistics(x() As Double, n As Integer)

Dim rang As Double
Dim maxVal As Single
Dim i As Integer
Dim mean As Single
Dim minVal As Double

i = 0
maxVal = x(0)
For i = 1 To UBound(x)
    If maxVal < x(i) Then
         maxVal = x(i)
    End If
Next i

'Computes mean average
i = 0
mean = x(0)
For i = 1 To UBound(x)
    mean = mean + x(i)
Next i
mean = mean / n

'Computes the lowest value
i = 0
minVal = x(0)
For i = 1 To UBound(x)
    If minVal > x(i) Then
         minVal = x(i)
    End If
Next i

'Calulates Range
rang = maxVal - minVal

end sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you've declared local variables in both procedures with the same ***name*** and are expecting them to be the same ***variable***. For example, you use the variable `minVal` in `SampleStats`, but you never give it a value. The fact that you declared a separate variable with the same name in `ComputeStatistics` is irrelevant.

Combine your code into one procedure as it is one logical block anyway. Then you won't have to worry about passing values back and forth.

Once you get that working if you still want to factor out the `ComputeStatistics` part, pass in all variables that you want to be updated (e.g. minVal, maxVal, rang, etc.) and don't declare them in the `ComputeStatistics` procedure.